# Pair items in two lists

Tags: python

i have two lists:

```
foo = ['learn.py', 'work.py','entertain.py','else']
bar = ['A.learn.py', '3.entertain.py','&work.py']
```

The result i want is

```
('learn.py', 'A.learn.py'), ('work.py', '&work.py'), 
('entertain.py','3.entertain.py'), ('else','else')]
```

Here follows my codes:

```
zoo = []
for j in bar:
    for i in foo:
        if i in j:
            zoo.append((i,j))
In [3]: zoo
Out[3]: [('learn.py', 'A.learn.py'), ('work.py', '&work.py')]
```

or,

```
zoo = []
for i in foo:
    for j in bar:
        if i in j:
            zoo.append((i,j))
In [5]: zoo
Out[5]: [('learn.py', 'A.learn.py'), ('work.py', '&work.py')]
```

How to solve such a problem?

Comment: Is `'3.enterain.py'` supposed to be `'3.entertain.py'`?

Comment: I made that assumption in my answer, but the result he wants also contains that misspelling.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, `bar` contains elements which themselves contain an element from `foo`, correct? Note the reason why `entertain.py` is not included in your current list is because it's misspelled in `bar`. This should work:

```
foo = ['learn.py', 'work.py','entertain.py','else']
bar = ['A.learn.py', '3.entertain.py','&work.py']
zoo = []
for i in foo:
    item = next((item for item in bar if i in item), None)
    if item:
        zoo.append((i, item))
    else:
        zoo.append((i,i))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the string `endswith()` method to check for matches and an `else:` on inner `for j in bar:` loop to handle the situation when no matches are found:

```
foo = ['learn.py', 'work.py', 'entertain.py', 'else']
bar = ['A.learn.py', '3.entertain.py', '&work.py']

zoo = []
for i in foo:
    for j in bar:
        if j.endswith(i):  # Match?
            zoo.append((i, j))
            break
    else:
        zoo.append((i, i))

print(zoo)
```

Output:

```
[('learn.py', 'A.learn.py'), ('work.py', '&work.py'), ('entertain.py', '3.entertain.py'), ('else', 'else')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as said before, assuming `'3.enterain.py'` is mispelled, you can try this:

```
foocpy = foo.copy()

zoo = [(f, b) for f, b in product(foo, bar) if f in b and not foocpy.remove(f)]
zoo+= [(f, f) for f in foocpy]

del foocpy
```

Otherwise, implement your own comparison check instead of using `in`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw something in here for fun (that still answers the question).
Why not use Levenshtein Distance when the opportunity arises.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import itertools

new_list_y =[]
for num_x, x in enumerate(foo):
    for num_y, y in enumerate(bar):
        if fuzz.ratio(x, y) > 85:
            new_list_y.append(y)
    if num_x > num_y:
        new_list_y.append(x)

list(itertools.zip_longest(foo, new_list_y))
```

Result:

```
[('learn.py', 'A.learn.py'),
 ('work.py', '&work.py'),
 ('entertain.py', '3.entertain.py'),
 ('else', 'else')]
```